# Edit Chef Client configuration with Knife Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, chef-infra

I'm creating virtual Machines on Azure running the following command:

```
knife azure server create --azure-dns-name 'XXXX' --azure-source-image "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-Datacenter-201408.01-en.us-127GB.vhd" --azure-service-location "East US" -P "XXXX" -z Small -x "XXXXX" --tcp-endpoints '3389:3389,5985:5985' -VV
```

It's working fine until I try to execute recipes. I've checked the client.rb inside this new virtual machine and it looks like this:

```
log_level        :info
log_location     STDOUT

chef_server_url  "http://localhost:8889"
validation_client_name "xxx-validator"
client_key        "c:/chef/client.pem"
validation_key    "c:/chef/validation.pem"

file_cache_path   "c:/chef/cache"
file_backup_path  "c:/chef/backup"
cache_options     ({:path => "c:/chef/cache/checksums", :skip_expires => true})

node_name "XXXX"
```

It's not working because the chef_server_url  is not that. I would like to know how can I set the correct chef server url, since I'm creating a new virtual machine, so edit this file won't work. Is there any special parameter that I'm missin on knife azure server create?

Answer (score 1):

The `chef_server_url` defaults to match the same URL that knife is using. You can configure this in your `.chef/knife.rb` file locally. Make sure that knife commands like `knife client list` are working correctly before trying to spawn a new instance.

Comment: Actually it was a conflict with the parameter -z. I've changed to --azure-vm-size and it worked. Thanks